# Executable run from electron project isn't loading resources

Tags: html, c++, exe, electron

I am making a electron application that launches an executable stored on my computer when run. If I run the exe by itself, it works correctly and loads all of the fonts. However, when run by the electron app, it opens, but non of the font files can be loaded. The exe is a compiled release project made in visual studio.

I tried putting the res folder into the same directory as index.html to no avail.

Code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <script>
      var child = require('child_process').execFile;
      var exePath = "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\Visual Studio    2015\\Projects\\Ten\\Release\\Ten.exe";
      var parameters = ["test"];

      child(exePath, parameters, function(err, data){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data.toString());
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code for main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

function createWindow () {
// Create the browser window.
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

// and load the index.html of the app.
win.loadURL(url.format({
pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true
}))

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {

  win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {

if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
  app.quit()
}
  })

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your exe use a relative path to load the fonts? If so, either change the exe to be more flexible, or in your call to `execFile()` specify the optional 3rd arg to specify the desired working directory.

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var exePath = "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Ten\\Release";
var exe = exePath + "\\Ten.exe";
var parameters = ["test"];
var options = {cwd:exePath};

child(exePath, parameters, options, function(err, data){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
```

If that doesn't work, my guess would be some kind of permissions problem. Is your electron app running as a different user to when you test the exe?